# Troubled With Scanning Conditionals

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am coding a questionnaire and after a certain section the program asks "Is that complete?" and it should be a yes or no answer. So I coded these conditionals but am getting a "incompatible types" error message.

```
System.out.println("Is that complete?");
String answer = sc.nextLine();
if(answer="no")
{
    System.out.println("Continue:");
    Continued = sc.nextLine();
    if(answer="yes")
    {
        System.out.println("Okay.");
        if(answer != "yes" || "no")
        System.out.println("That is not a valid input.");
        isThatComplete();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: **Why** did you write them that way?

Comment: You are mistyping `==` (comparison) as `=` (assignment), though I hear that in Java you’re supposed to use `.equals` anyways. Also, `answer != "yes" || "no"` doesn’t work. `||` is an operator like any other; you need to give it appropriate operands, i.e. `!(answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"))`.

Answer (score 0):

`if (answer != "yes" || "no")`

The `||` operator works with booleans but you are providing a boolean and a String, since it's parsed as

```
(answer != "yes") || "no")
```

A correct way to write it would be

```
if (!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no"))
```

or, according to De Morgan law:

```
if (!(answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"))
```

Mind that I used `equals(..)` instead of `==` because equality between objects shouldn't be checked with `==`, which merely checks references.

Answer (score 0):

Following line is incorrect. It is expecting boolean while you are giving it a String.

`if(answer="no")`

You should use == instead of =. Anyway, a better way to do this would be:

`if("no".equals(answer))`

Try same thing for if checks.

By the way - your code looks really bad. I am not sure what you are trying to do here: `if(answer != "yes" || "no")`.